# Outgoing e-mail from Exim server is rejected by Hotmail

Tags: networking, email, dns, exim

I am trying to send e-mails from an account using the webmail interface. When sending the test to a hotmail account, it is rejected immediately.

To investigate the issue, I used https://mxtoolbox.com/deliverability page and it shows that "::1" IP address is blacklisted. Then I saw the e-mail header and this shows:

`Received: from [::1] (port=60116 helo=node4037.myfcloud.com)`

I think that "::1" is the problem since this IP is the localhost address. How can I change that? Does it have something to do with reverse DNS?

Any help will be appreciated.

I have root access to my exim server and to the DNS server if there is some configuration to change.

EDIT:

[image: Deliverability result]

EDIT:

This is the full header:

```
From contacto@gestioncasinos.cl  Tue Jun 29 07:34:34 2021
Return-Path: <contacto@gestioncasinos.cl>
X-Original-To: ping@tools.mxtoolbox.com
Delivered-To: tools@tools.mxtoolbox.com
Received: from li1103-31.members.linode.com (li1103-31.members.linode.com [45.79.4.31])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by tools.mxtoolbox.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 32CB7B5F22
    for <ping@tools.mxtoolbox.com>; Tue, 29 Jun 2021 07:34:34 -0500 (CDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=gestioncasinos.cl; s=default; h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:
    Message-ID:Subject:To:From:Date:MIME-Version:Sender:Reply-To:Cc:Content-ID:
    Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc
    :Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:
    List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
    bh=kALiBgtrlgu0oxGdsDEFQfVmKWVoJe541W36WUyhD6w=; b=v9X2zw57EGu6OND48ZZ7NRCpOA
    gidwutd6UOcc0x2wX2c2F3f0dihIhSDCE+X2fOrH3Rn56lk5nmh74wcOnjahPxjZ2geYt14Wrpxu8
    LU3P2sPViyIdOqMPOKgM9m+XeVRJCy44cmXfLwRXaCUUF1PoS4ay5Wk7hSDqiapQ0kwaTXcJBcxtb
    5MtWnzeJw1g+hTY8d5SaD9E9Vf+JmqaYMOKyl/iJMcxSXxTBaZWFXFjMcGl1Z7ZV+X8ku4VPjPAEh
    fOChF3T81oBIsadZrMtlr4vlA1Uhx0W4ObggGFO42Az+51S1aRDBPx4CC+VZGmeFjbWL98NYwfcLO
    DIzrPQUg==;
Received: from [::1] (port=60116 helo=node4037.myfcloud.com)
    by node4037.myfcloud.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.94.2)
    (envelope-from <contacto@gestioncasinos.cl>)
    id 1lyCwe-000698-9A
    for ping@tools.mxtoolbox.com; Tue, 29 Jun 2021 08:34:33 -0400
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 29 Jun 2021 08:34:32 -0400
From: =?UTF-8?Q?Gesti=C3=B3n_de_Casinos?= <contacto@gestioncasinos.cl>
To: ping@tools.mxtoolbox.com
Subject: Testing
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.4.11
Message-ID: <8a083255d04bf913eee4f59fa1fc1fc0@gestioncasinos.cl>
X-Sender: contacto@gestioncasinos.cl
Organization: Desytec Ltda.
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - node4037.myfcloud.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - tools.mxtoolbox.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - gestioncasinos.cl
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: node4037.myfcloud.com: authenticated_id: contacto@gestioncasinos.cl
X-Authenticated-Sender: node4037.myfcloud.com: contacto@gestioncasinos.cl
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: 

This is just a test.
```

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Localhost is only reachable from localhost. This isn't your problem. Please provide all headers.

Comment: @DanielB added to the question.

Comment: MxToolbox's complaint seems nonsensical. Plenty of mail systems carry messages through internal hops before reaching the internet (even Gmail does); the 'Received' headers only exist for the admin's information and should not influence the deliverability.

Comment: @user1686 So how can I know the exact reason why Hotmail is rejecting the e-mails? I had made the test using recipient in Hotmail but actually I am having problems with recipients in other servers also.